# How to remove grad_fn when printing neural network weights

Tags: python, pytorch, neural-network

I have a neural net that uses nn.Linear connections between layers. When printing the weights between input and hidden layers with the code below:

```
print("Weight:", net.fc1.weight[0])
```

The print out looks like this:

```
Weight: tensor([ 0.0375,  0.1901,  0.0787,  0.2476,  0.0740,  0.2848, -0.2852, -0.0864,
     0.1827,  0.1384], grad_fn=<SelectBackward0>)
```

Is there a way to stop printing out the `grad_fn=<SelectBackward0>` and just print the weights out like this:

```
Weight: tensor([ 0.0375,  0.1901,  0.0787,  0.2476,  0.0740,  0.2848, -0.2852, -0.0864,
 0.1827,  0.1384])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `.data` attribute

```
print("Weight:", net.fc1.weight[0].data)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
weight_without_grad = net.fc1.weight[0].clone().requires_grad_(False)
print("Weight:", weight_without_grad)
```

This clones the tensor and print it. another way is using `detach()` but I wont suggest because as the name suggests it detaches the tensor